# iOS , why observeValueForKeyPath: is sync

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, key-value-observing

Today, I found KVO call-back function `- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context` is sync function, example:

First, I add observer:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"age" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

Second, I set callback:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context{
    NSLog(@"keyPath->%@",keyPath);
    sleep(3);
}
```

Third, I change `age`:

```
self.age = @"12312";
NSLog(@"postEnd");
```

then log

```
keyPath->age
//after 3 seconds 
postEnd
```

Why 3 seconds after log `postEnd`?

Comment: Because you have added `sleep(3)` which stops the execution for 3 seconds

Comment: Why wouldn't it be synchronous?

Comment: What is the purpose of your question I don't see any problem here?

Comment: It is synchronous. The observer takes three seconds because someone put a sleep (3) call in there.

Comment: The interviewer asked me, i don't know  the purpose of question

Answer (score 0):

Key-value observing always occurs on the thread that the change takes place in and it is always synchronous. This means that you have control over the threading but you also know that all the observing has been completed by the time your code to set the value has completed.

See [this article](https://www.objc.io/issues/7-foundation/key-value-coding-and-observing/#key-value-observing-and-threading) on KVO for more details and a lot more information about KVO.